# CSS and Images don't load on Page Load, but loads on page Refresh

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, zend-framework

All,

I have a PHP MVC application with the following structure:

```
helloworld
 - application
     - configs
     - controllers
     - models
     - layouts
 - include
 - library
 - public
    - .htaccess
    - index.php
    - design
      - css
         - style.css
         - struct.css
      - js
      - images
        - bg.gif
```

I have configured a virtual host in apache called `hello` that points to `helloworld/public/` folder. So, when I view my site, using `http://hello` all the CSS and images render fine.

I deployed my site to a different server with similar config as above. When I access the website using `http://test.com/hello` the CSS and the background images contained in it, renders absolutely fine in Chrome and Safari, but background images fail on IE,Firefox and Opera. When the page refreshes on these browsers, it works just fine. I am unable to understand the behavior for this.

The URLs in my CSS are written like this:

```
background-image: url(/design/images/bg.gif);
```

and my htaccess is like this:

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes

#####################################################
# CONFIGURE media caching
#
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
#
#####################################################

RewriteEngine   On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can somebody explain why Background images and CSS is not rendering properly on page load, but renders after a page refresh?

Comment: Are you sure the `design` folder isn't under `public`? I don't see how it could work otherwise. Also, try using an HTTP monitor like Firebug's "Net" tab or Fiddler to see what's happening in the responses from your image / CSS requests.

Comment: yep.. design folder is under public folder.. I will correct it.. Thanks

Comment: this still doesnt resolve the problem though

Comment: That's why it wasn't an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

let do some testing to  identify the problem

1- try to access http://test.com/hello/design/images/bg.gif    ,it should be accessible , if not then its permission problem

2- then try to use absolute  url in your css files like `background-image: url(http://test.com/hello/design/images/bg.gif);`

3- if you still face the problem then its design issue , i guess you are using IE 6 [check out here](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tutorials/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#background-flicker)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment deflate option on your .htaccess, perhaps your server don't have mod_deflate activated.

```
#SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```